# Difference between consecutive squarefree (cubefree) numbers

Tags: number-theory

The jumping champions for the greatest difference between consecutive
squarefree numbers are :

```
? n=1;maxi=0;while(maxi<100,m=n;gef=0;while(gef==0,m=m+1;  if(issquarefree(m)==1,g
ef=1));d=m-n;if(d>maxi,maxi=d;print(n,"  ",m,"   ",d));n=m)

1  2   1
3  5   2
7  10   3
47  51   4
241  246   5
843  849   6
22019  22026   7
217069  217077   8
1092746  1092755   9
8870023  8870033   10
221167421  221167433   12
```

The jumping chapions for the greatest difference between consecutive cubefree
 numbers are :

```
? n=1;maxi=0;while(maxi<10,m=n;gef=0;while(gef==0,m=m+1;w=factor(m);w=component(
w,2);if(vecmax(w)<3,gef=1));d=m-n;if(d>maxi,maxi=d;print(n,"   ",m,"   ",d));n=m
)

1   2   1
7   9   2
79   82   3
1374   1378   4
22623   22628   5
18035621   18035627   6
```

My questions :

- How far have these tables been calculated ?
- What is a good estimate of the first occurence of a length $\ge k$ in both cases ?

Comment: Related: http://oeis.org/A045882